# Enabling react-router's 'browserHistory' to work on live server

Tags: express, reactjs, heroku, server, browser-history

I have built a React app which I can deploy on my dev server, and everything works fine. I now want to upload it to a remote server, but this is where I run into trouble.

I've done a bit of reading around about this, and I'm finding the terminology a bit dense and impenetrable, so would really appreciate if someone could help to spell this out for me.

As far as I understand, if you are using `hashHistory`, you have 'ugly' URLs but the advantage is it can be deployed on a live server.

In contrast, using `browserHistory` (as I am) gives you 'pretty' URLs, but creates problems when you want to upload to a server, specifically when you page refresh at a nested URL, as the server doesn't understand this - react-router is creating fake URLs which are used to generate the correct javascript to load components where needed.

This much I understand (or please correct me if I don't appear to).

Without delving head first into serverside JS, I want to know how to fix this *specific* problem.

I have read about Heroku - but after installing, it didn't seem to give much guidance on how to get everything up and running. I've seen configs which included a `server.js` file which hooks the app up to an express server, but this also loses me a bit.

Would really appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction, bearing in mind this is totally new territory for me! Would really appreciate explanations of terminology and as much detail as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*Warning: Its just a beginning level answer. Read with your own risk.*

> Ok.. Lets start by believing one thing. `Every Web App Serve By Server`;

**Now, How it working?**

*Case 1:* You request for file by URL as `http://mart71.com/index.html` or `http://mart71.com` and it serve you `index.html`

*Case 2:*  Your request for `http://mart71.com/products/2` and it response with product page (dynamic) which as Id:2

**Ok.. Now How `Single Page Application` work?**

In case of `SPA`, your every request should be handled by `index.html`
so, You request for `http://mart71.com`, server serve 'index.html' with all its `javascript` files and your Javascript run and show what need to be displayed on lending page.

You request for another URI as `http://mart71.com/products/2`, first its load `index.html` with all its `javascript` and `Javascript`  run and push Browser history state to `products/2` (url change) and display page. In this case, your server has no idea what actually displaying on that page.

**What all this means?**

```
Simply, setup your server to serve all request by `index.html`
```

**How to do that?**

*Nginx : on nginx.conf*

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404; // means what ever the url is, serve index.html
}
```

*Apache: on .htaccess or .conf*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

*node.js express.js*

```
don't try this at production.. considered as bad practice. Use Nginx or Apache as proxy server.
```

Comment: Such a perfect answer! Thank you very much, I am a newbie so this solution from a newbie perspective was perfect!